# Validate Python Tkinter name entry by clicking button?

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

So here I have a program which first displays a information message and then you click next and it tells you to input your name before opening up the main window.

INFO ->(next) ENTER NAME ->(next)

When I enter my name in the entry box I want it to be checked that it does not contain 1.numbers and 2.is not blank. under the validate="key" option it means that once I start typing it validates. But rather I want it to only check the name once i press the NEXT button... If not it will open errorbox()

```
class errorbox():
    def __init__(self):
        windowError = Tk()
        windowError.title("Error")
        windowError.geometry('300x400')
        error_message = Label(windowError, font=("Bold", 10), justify="left", text="Please enter a valid name")
        
def clicked1():
    description.configure(text="Please enter your name")
    nameBox = Entry(windowSplash, width=20, textvariable=name)
    nameBox.place(rely=0.5, x=130, anchor=W)
    reg = windowSplash.register(validate)
    nameBox.config(validate="none",validatecommand=clicked2)
    button2 = Button(text="Next", bg="white", width=5, command=lambda:[clicked2(),validate()])
    button2.place(rely=0.5, x=300, anchor=E)
    button1.destroy()

def validate(input):
    if input.isdigit():
        print("Invalid name was entered" + input)
        errorbox()
        return False
    elif input is "":
        print("No name entered")
        errorbox()
        return False
    else:
        
        return True

def clicked2():
    print(name.get(), "logged in...")
    windowSplash.destroy()
    windowTool = Tk()
    windowTool.title("Radial Measurements Calculator Tool")
    windowTool.geometry('300x400')

name = StringVar()

windowSplash.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is unclear what your question is, or what the nature of your problem is.  I assume that you have posted this code because you expected that it should work, but that it is not working -- is this correct?  If so, please indicate what behavior you are observing that is not in line with your expectations.

Comment: @KDN I have updated my question... Under the def validate(input): section as well

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Community.

I might have interpreted your question, but please make sure that next time you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you ask.

Here are a couple of things that I have observed.

1. The `validate` function takes `input` as a parameter, so make sure you pass that in the lambda function by `lambda input = name.get(): [clicked2(),validate(input)]`.
2. By checking `input.isdigit()` does not guarantee that there might not be numbers after/between characters, so I suggest you to iterate through the string and check for `isdigit()`/`type()` or use `re` module. Also, an efficient way to check for empty string could be `if not name.get():`.
3. If you aim to open the new window only after the validation, I suggest you to call `clicked2` from the `validate` function under a condition and not form the `next` button, because in this case your return form `validate` isn't used for anything.